# Run Foreach Loop Aysnc

Tags: c#

I have small problem in updating status of the product in Async so just need your help to resolve this

Below are the two methods I have. One is to update Single Product status and the other is to update multiple product status. In `UpdateInventoryStatusofMultipleProduct` method I have to call `UpdateInventoryStatusofSingleProduct` to update status of multiple products.
To update each product status it will take some time. When I update status of mutiple products I don't want to wait for other product status to be updated. I mean I want to update status of products asynchronously

```
public bool UpdateInventoryStatusofSingleProduct(Product product)
{      
    result = this.inventory.UpdateProductStatus(storageLocation, state);
    Thread.Sleep(1000); //Allow the System to update status
    return result;  
}

public bool UpdateInventoryStatusofMultipleProduct(List<Product> products)
{      
    //How to change foreach loop to run asynchronously
    foreach (var product in products)
    {
       bool result = UpdateInventoryStatusofSingleProduct(product);  
    }                 
}
```

I am thinking to implement this like this but `UpdateInventoryStatusofSingleProduct` should return task but current signature of the method doesn't do that. I don't want to change the signature of `UpdateInventoryStatusofSingleProduct`.

```
public bool UpdateInventoryStatusofMultipleProduct(List<Product> products)
{      
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var product in products)
    {
       tasks.Add(UpdateInventoryStatusofSingleProduct(product));  
    }                 
}
```

Comment: WHy do you have an arbitrary thread sleep in your update in the first place. That smells of something wrong upstream.

Comment: When you say *async*, you really mean *in background*, isn't it?

Comment: You do not want to update _asynchronously_ if " I don't want to wait for other product status to be updated", you want to update statuses _in parallel_. For this you may use [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I believe Parallel.ForEach works for me

Comment: Please remember to accept my answer and vote it up then: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1):

Isn't `Parallel.ForEach` what you want?

```
public bool UpdateInventoryStatusofMultipleProduct(List<Product> products)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(products, product => UpdateInventoryStatusofSingleProduct(product));
}
```

It executes a `foreach` operation in which iterations may run *in parallel*: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Parallel won't run it async.

Comment: No, but it will run the operations in *in parallel*. What's your point?

Comment: OP asked to report progress when individual product is updated. Parallel may finish fast but it will be stuck unless all products are updated.

Comment: If you want to offload the calling thread for any reason, the entire UpdateInventoryStatusofMultipleProduct method should be called on another thread.

Comment: @mm8 you're not going to be freeing up threads, and the OP is doing a thread sleep which will block for 1 second instead of properly implementing async

Comment: @vendettamit parallel won't run it async, but the OP does not want to wait... And async will wait (it will wait asynchronously though - the only thing async actually can do).

Answer (score 0):

As @mm8 says, you could potentially Parallel for each, or if you want to use tasks you can create a new task by something similar to this:

```
foreach (var product in products)
{
   tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => UpdateInventoryStatusofSingleProduct(product)));  
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks); ...
```

Comment: Why would you start a task for each Product when you can use the built-in Parallel.ForEach method to perform the operations in parallel?

Comment: Who knows, he asking about tasks. Why would you normally thread.sleep for a second?

Comment: For the above code I need to change my method as Async and also return type should be Task which I dont want to do...So I planning to go with Parallel.ForEach